# Why does my FB.api User object no longer contain the "link" field?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My website invokes the Facebook API to retrieve a user's info as follows:

```
FB.api('/' + uid, function(response)
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

where `uid` is my own id. The [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) states that this should include a `link` field, and it certainly used to. It states that no auth token is required for that (though I supply one anyway). And yet the actual response I get contains the following fields:

```
{"id":, "name":, "first_name":, "last_name":, "username":, "gender":, "locale":}
```

(values removed)

What happened to `link` and how do I get it back? I still get the link if I request the exact same thing via the Graph API Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure why the link field is missing here, but here are some possible solutions:

First, you can try using "/me" instead of "/user-id". I do this on a site with fb integration, and it will return a link.

Second, you can try asking for the field specifically. You can append the desired fields to a graph api call, like "/123456789?fields=link,first_name"

Last, if all else fails, you could always just generate the link with the userID you have. For example: var url = "http://www.facebook.com/" + userId;

I realize this does not explain the absence of the link field from your responses, but hopefully it will help you find a solution.

Comment: Even with the explicit `fields` request, I still don't receive the link. Really weird. Will construct the link manually as a work-around for now.

Comment: Did you try making a call to "/me" instead of the user id of the logged-in user?